# Fragments Memory Managment

Tags: android, memory-management, fragment

i am placing the list view on item click listener code for you reference.on each item click in the list view i am replacing the fragment with another fragment.i placed the main fragment(fragment 1) in the frame layout file.i am just switching the fragments in the same view.

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg) {

                  if(array[position].equalsIgnoreCase("movies")){
                       FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                       transaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, new next());

                       transaction.commit();
                  }
                  if(array[position].equalsIgnoreCase("serials")){
                       FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                   transaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, new Item2());

                       transaction.commit();
                 }  
                  if(array[position].equalsIgnoreCase("restaurents")){
                       FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                   transaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, new Item3());

                       transaction.commit();
                 }     
                   } 
                });
```

if i click on **movies** the fragment1 is replaced by new fragment(Item 1) similarly 
 if i click on **serials** the fragment1 is replaced by new fragment(Item 2) 
 i am thinking that the fragment1 memory will be deallocated when i switch to the new fragment(Item 1) and the fragment(Item 1) will be deallocated when i click on the fragment(Item 2),tell me it will work in the same manner or not. because i need to use  more number of fragments for every list item click(The number of items in the list will be more) . i want to know whether it will happens in the same way or not is there any way to manage the memory for fragments. suggest me a better way to do this because i want my application to run with out memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple check this by using fragments lifecycle methods.

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Fragment1 onStart");
  }

  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Fragment1 onResume");
  }

  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Fragment1 onPause");
  }

  public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Fragment1 onStop");
  }

  public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Fragment1 onDestroyView");
  }

  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Fragment1 onDestroy");
  }

  public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Fragment1 onDetach");
  }
```